# How to mock the same request of different origins URLs (for TestCafe)

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to mock the same request, that is initiated by 2 different origins (url1, url2).
But the only one request (from 1st origin url1) is mocked.
How to work with multiple origins?
Thanks in advance.

```
const urlRegExp = new RegExp('/events');
const mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo(urlRegExp)
    .respond({eenter code hererror: 'this request has been mocked'}, 500, {
        'access-control-allow-origin': 'url1.com',
        'access-control-allow-credentials': true
    })
    .onRequestTo(urlRegExp)
    .respond({error: 'this request has been mocked'}, 500, {
        'access-control-allow-origin': 'url2.com',
        'access-control-allow-credentials': true
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your `onRequestTo` calls. Please take a look at the [Filter With Predicate section](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto.html#filter-with-a-predicate) of TestCafe documentation.

```
const mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo(request => {
        return request.url === 'http://example.com' &&
               request.method === 'post' &&
               request.isAjax &&
               request.body.toString() === 'foo=bar';
    })
    .respond(/*...*/);
```

You can set your request mock to filter requests by request headers such as host, referer, origin, etc. Thus you need to write different filters for your different requests.